# Windows "jupyter notebook" command failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, jupyter

Running `jupyter notebook` returns `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2`

(In general, all commands `jupyter subcommand` fail this way)

However, running `jupyter-notebook` works just fine.

Also, running `jupyter` works fine, just says an argument is required.

"C:\Python36\Scripts" is in my PATH environment variable, and both `jupyter.exe` and `jupyter-notebook.exe` are there.

I'm running python 3.6 on Windows 10, ipykernel 5.1.0, notebook 5.7.4, ipython 7.2.0, jupyter was installed via pip

I tried reinstalling jupyter, but nothing changed. I need `jupyter subcommand` to work because some external scripts which I can't change use it and fail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the result for `where jupyter` ?

Comment: Yes, ```C:\Python36\Scripts\jupyter.exe```

Comment: Are you able to run `ipython notebook` to open the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yup, ```ipython notebook``` works